# Consecutive equation numbers with different section numbers in the front

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering

I am looking for commands that enable me to have consecutive equation numbers with different section numbers in the front. For example, when the last equation of section 2 is (2.18), the next equation in section 3 should be (3.19). Any idea will be appreciated.

Document class:
I'm using a handout document class. It is based on the article class. It is designed for creating handouts for a college class. Commands that work for the article class also work in this document class.

Comment: @marmot Yes. this is based on the article document class with minor edits.

Comment: @marmot Sorry, I couldn't post it here, because my mentor created this document class, not me. One thing for sure is that commands that work for the article class also work in this document class.

Comment: Well, then try `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` in the preamble of the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'll be happy to delete this but perhaps it might be useful for those who cannot share their document class with us.) A rather basic way to achieve this numbering is to use

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test a}
\begin{equation}
 E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\section{Test b}
\begin{equation}
 E=h\nu
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```